# Swift - Load Contact Page with Keyboard Open

Tags: ios, swift

I am making a simple contact us form containing Name, Email Address and Message. The following code in my viewDidLoad is a snippet of the Name text field. I would like the keyboard to open on this field when I open the contact form.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    let fullNameInput = UITextField()
    fullNameInput.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 15, width: self.view.frame.width - 2 * margin, height: 50)
    fullNameInput.placeholder = "Your Name"
    let fullNameString = "Your Name"
    let fullNamePlaceholder = NSMutableAttributedString(string: fullNameString)
    let fullNameRange = (fullNameString as NSString).range(of: fullNameString)
    fullNamePlaceholder.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.white, range: fullNameRange)
    fullNameInput.attributedPlaceholder = fullNamePlaceholder
    fullNameInput.backgroundColor = .black
    fullNameInput.delegate = self
    fullNameInput.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    fullNameInput.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    fullNameInput.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

    fullNameInput.becomeFirstResponder()
    self.view.addSubview(fullNameInput)
}
```

In browsing for a solution I believe

```
fullNameInput.becomeFirstResponder()
```

to be the line of code I wish to achieve this. But, it is not doing so. Am I missing something here?

**Additional Question**

Following this I would also make a scrollview for the area ABOVE the open keyboard.

How can I also get the frame of the keyboard?

I am using Swift 3.0 and iOS 9.2

Comment: first of all, call `super.viewDidLoad()` when u are overriding any lifecycle function in your vc.

Comment: what OS version are u using? What Swift version? Pasting your code to my sample project on Swift 3.0 running on iOS 10.3 Simulator is opening the keyboard.

Comment: Swift 3.0 and iOS 9.2. I have added this info to my question, thank you. I have also accepted a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call this from **viewDidAppear**

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    fullNameInput.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: you should be using the `animated` property upon calling super, not hard coding `true`.

Answer (score 2):

From [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621113-becomefirstresponder) on `becomeFirstResponder()`:

> Never call this method on a view that is not part of an active view
>   hierarchy.

So calling it from `viewDidLoad` is definitelly not a good idea. Try from `viewDidAppear`

Answer (score 0):

You are making the `fullNameInput` become first responder before it was included in the view.

Just add it as subview first, then call it as first responder and it will work.

And I would do as mag_zbc said. Use the become first responder on the `ViewDidAppear`